# jQuery animating issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

So far, I have a pretty decent code to animate a center box. For some reason, when I preview this on different browsers and computer (Mac and PC) I get different results. One may show a faster animation speed, while the other is perfect. I have also noticed that when the box is being animated from left to right, there is a stutter, and the animation jerks. I can't really explain it more than that. My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        isAnimating = false;

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.arrow-left', function() {
    if(isAnimating) return;

    isAnimating = true;
    var $current = $(this).parents('.signupBox');
    var $next = $(this).parents('.signupBox').next();

    $current.stop(true,true).animate({
        left: "200%"
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        $current.css({
                left: "-200%"
            }).appendTo('.wrapper'); // move to end of stack

        $next.css({
                left: "-200%"
            }).stop(true,true).animate({
                left: "0%"
            }, 500, 'linear', function() {
                isAnimating = false;
            });
    });

}).on('click', '.arrow-right', function() {
    if(isAnimating) return;

    isAnimating = true;
    var $current = $(this).parents('.signupBox');
    var $next = $(this).parents('.signupBox').siblings().last();

    $current.stop(true,true).animate({
        left: "-200%"
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        $current.css({
                left: "200%"
            });

        $next.prependTo('.wrapper') // move to front of stack
            .css({
                left: "200%"
            }).stop(true,true).animate({
                left: "0%"
            }, 500, 'linear', function() {
                isAnimating = false;
            });
    });
});

});
```

Some CSS:

```
.signupBox:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.signupBox {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLaGk/) showing what happens, hopefully you can see what's the issue from there.

Then animation from right to left (click on the `<` symbol and you will see a slign change in speed.

Comment: @AlienArrays Where before, could you give me a snippet?

Comment: @EliteGamer before `.animate` like `.stop(true,true).animate({ ...`

Comment: Ok, thanks i will check and see the result. I am also getting a JSFIDDLE done now.

Comment: @mdesdev Done, but still no help with the issue.

Comment: @EliteGamer different browsers give different results, btw it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: @mdesdev Click the button `<` that animation jerks at the end. It is slight, but noticable.

Comment: @EliteGamer ok, this might help, try to add easing for animation after animation delay e.g. `500, 'linear', function() { ...` it should help, here's a [easing](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html) list. *NOTE: You must load jQuery UI library for easing.

Comment: @mdesdev It looks better an Google Chrome : Mac, but still jerks on the Chrome : PC. I am about to check safari on the Mac .. Safari on the Mac does the same as Chrome : PC ? hmmm

Comment: @EliteGamer like I was mentioned before, different browsers gives different results.

Comment: yes, but why would all the left to right animations be consistant, while the others vary @mdesdev

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers could have different results when using JS and css transitions, it actually depends on your machine speed, browser speed as well. It could depend on how many opened tabs you have in each browser, browsers plugins could freeze animations as well. Other JS events as well.

I have tested your code in Chrome, FF (wasn't able to check it in IE11, it seems there are JS errors on jsfiddler using jQuery). Didn't mentioned something strange.

I could recommend to use Greenshock JS animating library. http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/
They say it's x20 times faster jQuery animate. But i think actually may be in 2,3 )

That libruary is based on Flash library that was used by Action Script coders to create beauty animations in Flash.

Comment: Could you explain WHAT errors you found in jsfiddle?